# How to fix error 'Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for 'Static' in Unity 2D game engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, 2d, rigid-bodies

im following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynH51MiKutY&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuCVTz6lvhR81nnaf1a-b67U&index=8) and when i saved the Unity Engine didnt allow me to test my work because of an error. the full error says "Assets\scripts\VidaPlayer.cs(25,34): error CS0117: 'Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for 'Static' ".  It only detects the error on unity, in VS Studio doesnt show any error.

This is the script that i wrote:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LifePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private void Start()
    {
         anim= GetComponent<Animator>(); 
         rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

     private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
     {
         if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Trap"))
         {
            Death();
         }
     }

     private void Death()
     {
          rb.bodyType = Rigidbody2D.Static;//<-- where it shows the error
          anim.SetTrigger("death");
     }
}
```

i tried to remove all that is involved with the rb but it show me this error :

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.Graphs.Edge.WakeUp () (at <8e8a32ebae4d4c768ca69b7e552734c1>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.DoWakeUpEdges (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] inEdges, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] ok, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] error, System.Boolean inEdgesUsedToBeValid) (at <8e8a32ebae4d4c768ca69b7e552734c1>:0) UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.WakeUpEdges (System.Boolean clearSlotEdges) (at <8e8a32ebae`your text`4d4c768ca69b7e552734c1>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.WakeUp (System.Boolean force) (at <8e8a32ebae4d4c768

Comment: `RigidbodyType2D.Static` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyType2D.html

Comment: Can you please share a screen of your inspector window that shows all of the components of the object that the above script is attached to it? Also can you please share your "VidaPlayer" script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything seems working fine in the code  , Try exiting and restarting Unity if you open the player animator you will notice that it have disappeared this is a bug in unity
try restarting unity it should work again as intended

Answer (score 0):

Simple small typo

in Code :

```
rb.bodyType = Rigidbody2D.Static;//<-- where it shows the error
```

change to:

rb.bodyType = Rigidbody**Type**2D.Static;